# Add the ability to search through your own comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, search

When I go to see my comments, there are 11 pages of comments since my first comment, and I think many users have a lot more than me.

This morning I wanted to find a question that I commented on weeks before. It took me almost 10 minutes to find the question. Being able to search through your comments would help a lot here.

[image: Profile: "all actions" → "comments" → "201 Comments"]

I suggest a search box to the right of the "201 Comments" text.

Comment: For comments that are that old, they would be included in the data for a [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) query.  You _could_ write a query to "search" for a comment you made a while ago.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76958/search-your-comments

Comment: ["You can't at the moment. It's annoying to me, too."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23786/135615)

Comment: You can _sometimes_ find comments by doing a web search, restricted to the site you want, and including your user handle, as long as you remember some of the exact text of the comment. If you remember other involved usernames, that's usually really helpful too.

Comment: I have seen this topic raised before and i can't find the thread now. Yes it would be an awesome addition.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to search comments on *data.stackexchange.com*.

For example, if I go to *https://data.stackexchange.com/users/35449/barlop*, then it shows some queries, e.g., the following one lists all comments:

```sql
SELECT
  Id AS [Comment Link],
  Text
FROM Comments
where UserId=42672
```

Where it says 'search by name or URL', you can enter the particular site, e.g. Super User or Stack Overflow, and it autocompletes that field.

You might be able to adjust the query to search, but the easiest thing to do is to click the option to download the CSV file of the search results. Then you can open it in, a spreadsheet program e.g. Excel (or as a commenter points out, libre office calc), and search.

**Note**

The interface has changed a bit. The query works at this link and shows comments on Super User:  https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1359083

Comment: Or [Calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Calc).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes good point, the spreadsheet in libre office.. even I have started moving away from ms office  to libre office , and i've used ms office since the 1990s and knew ms word back to front!  I've updated my answer re that

Answer (score -12):

There are a few reasons I think this feature request would not be helpful.

- Comments are second-class citizens.  They are subject to deletion at any time, so using them to search for posts is unreliable.
- There are viable work-arounds.  For newer posts, the comment should be easy to find in your recent activity since they will be within the front-most pages of comment history.  For older posts, you can search for them with this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76958/search-your-comments) ([thanks to Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299466/why-doesnt-exist-an-search-to-your-own-comments-or-it-exists-and-i-dont-know#comment221413_299466) for finding it).
- There are better ways to mark "important" posts, including using the favorites feature.

Comment: Preemptively marking posts as important is great when it works. Usually it doesn't work. Personally, I use history search in my browser a good two orders of magnitude more than bookmark search... and not because I never bookmark things, either. Also, the Favorites feature is, if anything, more bizarrely fragile and hard to manage than comments are: I'd call it a third-class citizen.

Comment: As you said in 1st point, Comments are subject to deletion any time, the same apply to questions and answers also till certain point. SO I think this is not the valid reasoning behind delay this feature request. I think Comments are Communication between different users here, and that should be searchable. Otherwise Google will prevent your search in GMAIL till first page only.